# Permission denied when opening or creating files with PHP

Tags: php, file-io, ftp, file-permissions

I can't create files with php, because the file dosent got permission for that.
I get this error:

> Warning: fopen(test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /web/com/example.com/index.php on line 20
>   Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /web/com/example.com/index.php on line 21
>  
>   Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /web/com/example.com/index.php on line 22

This is the code I was using:

```
<?php
 $file = fopen("test.txt","w");
 echo fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
 fclose($file);
 ?>
```

Simple as that!  This is [example code from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fwrite.asp).

So I need help to find out how to give the file the needed permissions.
I'm uploading files to my site with the [net2ftp](http://net2ftp.com/) FTP web application, if it matters.

Comment: Read some tutorial to understand what you deal with, e.g. http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html - I think that will help you most.

Comment: It's going to depend on the server setup.  You'll need to find out what user your PHP process is running as, and apply read and write permissions for that user to the directory. There are some common defaults so if you can post what you're using to host, Apache, IIS, etc. it may help.

Comment: See permissions on server thru ssh (ls -l in directory)

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 29):

The folder your PHP script is trying to write to will probably be owned by the root user. Your PHP script is more than likely running under the www-data user if you're using a default Ubuntu/Apache/PHP setup.

As such you need to:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data folder
chmod -R g+w folder
```

If you find PHP is running under a user that is different from www-data then just change the user a group in the first line of code.

PS. change "folder" for your actual folder name.

Comment: Where do I type in that? When I tried to send that code to the ftp server, it responsed: 500 unknown command

Comment: It didn't know what "chown" command was, but it did know the "chmod" command, BUT! When I changed "folder" to any file or folder (for example "/index.php" or "/test" (I tested with and without the quotation marks and slashes)) it respnded this: 550 Could not change perms on g+w /test: No such file or directory

Comment: I assumed you were on the command line, not using an FTP client. You'd need to be on the command line to run a chown command really. The only other thing I can suggest in that case if to chmod the folder to 0777, but this isn't something I would really recommend.

Comment: I was using an FTP client! [link](http://net2ftp.com/)! 
I go to "Advanced", then "Send arbitrary FTP commands to the FTP server", and in the box I type the commands...

Answer (score 5):

The user running PHP (usually the apache user) doesn't have write permission on the folder the script is running in. Try using an absolute path, like "/tmp/test.txt" -- tmp is usually writable by any user, but the contents tend to be wiped out on reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu and i solved it by running the command below in one directory up from the folder(.i.e uploads) i was writing the files in.

```
sudo chmod 777 ./uploads
```

Comment: Warning: The permission 777 means that any user on your operating system can modify, execute, and write to the files posing a significant security risk to your system. An unauthorized user could use this to modify files to compromise your system.