# fopen() in PHP not creating or writing to txt file

Tags: php, fopen, permission-denied, lampp

I get the following Warning:

Warning: fopen(Uploaded_Files/dataFile1.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP_Course_Practice/Superglobals/data_upload.php on line 17

- I am using XAMPP for 7.4.8-0
- Using my MacBook as a Localhost to learn PHP. I am quite new to coding.
- I've tried:

  - writing the whole Path to the file dataFile1.txt in fopen() but it's not solving the problem
  - Checked in PHP.ini that allow_url_fopen is on
  - included whole path at the top of PHP file but also not solving the problem
  - Also tried `chown -R www-data:www-data folder` (where folder was full path to the folder) and Terminal said `chown: www-data: illegal group name`
  - Also tried `sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a daemon -t user wheel` (first to Superglobals Folder and then later to root folder of Xampp)
- The full Path that fopen() is trying to reach and write to file is:
  **/opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP_Course_Practice/Superglobals/Uploaded_Files/dataFile1.txt**
- I'm not keen on using 777 as I read in various articles that it's not safe to use.

**The Code is:**

```
<?php
$document_root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$fileRoot = $document_root . "/PHP_Course_Practice/Superglobals/Uploaded_Files/dataFile1.txt";
echo "Root: $document_root";
include($document_root . "/PHP_Course_Practice/Superglobals/Uploaded_Files/dataFile1.txt");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $dataFile1 = fopen("Uploaded_Files/dataFile1.txt", "w");
  $dataFile1Txt = "My age is " . $_POST["age"] . ".";
  fwrite($dataFile1, $dataFile1Txt);
  echo $dataFile1;
  fclose($dataFile1);
}
?>

<form action="data_upload.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="age">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission denied when opening or creating files with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200557/permission-denied-when-opening-or-creating-files-with-php)

Comment: I'm not a Mac user so I can't tell you the best practice in that platform but it's almost never a good idea to store user data right into application directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check the web user.

```php
<?php
echo exec("whoami");
```

And add the user to your group.

```sh
sudo usermod -a -G <groupName> <userName>
```

Final, check your files' permission setting.

Comment: Thanks, LianSheng. 

How could I check File's Permission Setting? Is it via using Terminal? And, what command should I write to check File's Permission Setting if it's in Terminal? Thank you again.

Comment: Using echo exec("whoami"); gave daemon. What do I write inside <groupName> <userName> in this case? Is daemon the groupName ?

Comment: @KodeMonk daemon is user name, group name is your directory owner's group. You can type `ls -l` to check owner and group.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answers. I tried, and it asked for Password. After putting in MacBook's password it says " sudo: usermod: command not found "

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I mistakenly thought that the commands for mac and linux are basically the same... Try it?  https://superuser.com/a/214311/1208900

Comment: No worries :-)  

From the link, I did the following but unfortunately issue not solved yet:
1. 'sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a daemon -t user wheel' (I first tried in Superglobals Folder. It asked for password, and then I thought daemon added to Superglobals folder. Then logged out of XAMPP, logged-in and reloaded Page but same as before.)

2. 1. sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a daemon -t user wheel (tried in root Folder of XAMPP. It asked for password, and then I thought daemon added to root folder. Then logged out of XAMPP, logged-in and reloaded Page but same as before.)

Comment: Sorry, I don’t have a Mac, so I don’t know what exactly you are experiencing. Maybe you can try the link in the comments below your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should try check the permission of the files or directory you want to open.
afterwards you can add the permission to read and write recursively to that directory as below

```
$ chmod -R 770 /path/toyour/directory
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell how to check the permission of the files or directory?

Comment: @KodeMonk use `ls -l /directoryname` or `ls -l /path/to/filename`

Answer (score 0):

The way I could solve it is to download and install the *Non*-Virtual Machine version of XAMPP. It seems that VM-version of XAMPP (LAMPP) is not suitable for permissions on a *localhost* unless perhaps you are keen on non-secure opening of 777.